# How to get SSRS Report using WebRequest?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, httpwebrequest

I'm always getting empty XML file using my code and getting filled XML file when running url from web browser (Chrome).
The url is the same in both cases (with same params)...  strings day&month are = "05"&"09"

```
string period = "From="+day+"/"+month+"/2018%2007:00:00&To="+day+"/"+month+"/2018%2009:00:00";
string response = doRequest(@"http://localserver/ReportServer?%2FSpecial%2FReport&"+period+"&rs:Format=XML");
```

---

```
private string doRequest(string url_with_params){

 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_with_params);
 request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
 request.PreAuthenticate = true;
 request.Credentials =  new NetworkCredential("login", "password");

 using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string responseText ="";
            using(var reader =  new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())){
                responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            };
            return responseText;
        }
        response.Close();
        return null;
  }
}
```

The XML file that I get running my code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Report xsi:schemaLocation="Special_x0020_Report http://localserver/ReportServer?%2FSpecial%2FReport&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="Special Report" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Special_x0020_Report"><Tablix1 /></Report>
```

Running from browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Report xsi:schemaLocation="Special_x0020_Report http://localserver/ReportServer?%2FSpecial%2FReport&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="Special Report" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="Special_x0020_Report"><Tablix1 /><Details_Collection>

<Details Name="Single" Qty="1" FailureCode="@BLOCK"/></Details_Collection></Report>
```